# How can I find a function that minimizes this given cost function?

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I am trying to find a function $f(x)$ that minimizes the following cost function

$$E = \left(\int_{-p}^p{{x^2\mathcal{N}(x)}f(x)}dx-\epsilon\right)^2$$

With $\epsilon\geq 0$ and $\mathcal{N}(x)$ a normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$

$$\mathcal{N}(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$$

and subject to the following constraints

$$\int_{-p}^p{f(x)\mathcal{N}(x)}dx = \beta$$

$$0\leq f(x) \leq 1$$

So far, I tried to solve this problem in a similar approach of a calculus of variations problem, by slghtly varying $f(x)\rightarrow f(x)+\delta\eta(x)$, with $\delta<<1$ and $\eta(x)$ an arbitrary continuous function. However, I am not sure that this is the right approach, nor am I sure that the final equation I am getting if correct.

I proposed the following functional $S = E[f] + \lambda(\int_{-p}^p{f(x)\mathcal{N}(x)}dx -\beta)$, with $\lambda$ a Lagrange multiplier, and tried to extreme it (e.g. first order variations in $f$ should verify $S[f+\delta\eta] - S[f] = \Delta S[f] + o(\delta^2)\rightarrow\Delta S[f]=0$). Then

$$S[f+\delta\eta] - S[f] = E[ f+\delta\eta] +  \lambda\left(\int_{-p}^p{[f(x)+\delta\eta(x)]\mathcal{N}(x)}dx - \beta\right) - S[f]\\
=2\delta\int_{-p}^p{{x^2\mathcal{N}(x)}f(x)}\int_{-p}^p{{x^2\mathcal{N}(x)}\eta(x)}dx
-2\delta\epsilon\int_{-p}^p{x^2\mathcal{N}(x)\eta(x)}dx+\delta\lambda\int_{-p}^p{\mathcal{N}(x)\eta(x)}dx + o(\delta^2)$$

Which leads to

$$\Delta S=2\int_{-p}^p{{x^2\mathcal{N}(x)}\eta(x)}dx\left[\int_{-p}^p{{x^2\mathcal{N}(x)}f(x)dx}
-\epsilon\right]+\lambda\int_{-p}^p{\mathcal{N}(x)\eta(x)}dx = 0$$

But here is where I get stuck. This final equation seems far more complex than Euler-Lagrange equations. I really have no idea how to continue. Does this make any sense or is there another way to proceed from scratch?

Comment: What do you mean be "solving" here? You want an exact analytical solution or a an approximate one?

Comment: @KBS I am trying to get an exact solution. However, given the complexity of the problem, I could be satisfied with an approximate result.

Comment: Right now I can only see an approximate polynomial solution. Note that since you are optimizing on a compact interval for $x$, then polynomials approximation are not that bad. Basically, you can choose a basis of polynomials and you will get in the cost some truncated moments of the normal distribution.

Comment: @KBS I see. And in such approximation, I could use the method of Lagrange multipliers to compute the coefficients of the expansion, or where you thinking of another way to obtain those coefficients?

Comment: For instance, yes.